# Can GDAL georeference a (KML) ground overlay?

Tags: raster, gdal, kml, gdal-python-binding

I'm using GDAL to georeference an image, but can't seem to find the
information that I need.

In the sample code below the upper left (ul) and lower right (lr)
corner coordinates denote not the corners of the image itself,
but the corners of the bounding-box that span the image once it's
been rotated around its midpoint (rotation).

I believe I've managed to translate the image as if these
coordinates were its corners but that's not quite right.
I could proceed by deducing the image corner coordinates and go from there but I'm hoping there's a way to let GDAL figure this out for me.

Is there some way I can feed GDAL with bounding-box
coordinates and rotation like this?

```
import gdal

ul = (18.019981384277344, 59.32425764439889)
lr = (18.103408813476562, 59.30586128759598)
rotation = -181.46  # what I need to include somehow

ds = gdal.Open('img.bmp')
gdal.Translate(
    'img.tiff',
    ds,
    outputBounds=[*ul, *lr],
    outputSRS='EPSG:4326',
)
```

Edit:

I've since figured out that the parameters I have correspond to a KML Ground Overlay and that this question is pretty much the same as [these](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17420/export-georeferenced-image-overlay-from-kml) [two](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352104/kml-image-overlay-conversion-with-gdal).

Comment: not sure that I understand exactly your goal, but it seems to me that you should use gdalWARP instead of translate

Comment: Yes to gdal.Warp.  Maybe find clues here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395999/gdal-gcp-python-georeferencing-fails-to-perform-thin-plate-spline-transformation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KML Image Overlay conversion with GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352104/kml-image-overlay-conversion-with-gdal)

Comment: it's already linked in the question @nmtoken

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've been able to gather there's no standard recipe in GDAL to perform this operation. However, there is a [plugin to QGIS](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-kmltools-plugin) that can and it outlines [the necessary transformations](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-kmltools-plugin/blob/master/createGroundOverlayGeoTiff.py) for the corresponding operation in GDAL.